# Solving double integrals using translated polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

how would you go about using translated polar coordinates $y= rsin(theta) +5$ and $x=rcos(theta)$ and to evaluate double integrals with $f(x,y)= x^2+y^2$ bound by the circle $x^2+y^2 = 2x$? Please and thanks. I just need a general idea.

Comment: Please do not keep changing your posted question. That becomes very frustrating for those who are trying to help you (who have already answered given the (original, then modified once, information)!

Comment: You should take the time to make it complete *from the start*, when you first post a question. It is very tiresome to try to answer a *moving target.*

Comment: I think I got it now thanks to you guys and especially @John Habert

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.

Comment: sorry @amWhy my bad I'll be more clear next time :D!

Answer (score 2):

**Based on original information** (including first modification of question)

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2,\quad x = r\cos \theta,\quad y = r\sin\theta$

If bounded by $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$, that means the function is bounded by $$r^2 = 2r\cos \theta \iff r^2 - 2\cos\theta = 0 \iff r(r-2\cos\theta) = 0 \iff r = 0,\; r=2\cos \theta$$ So your bounds of integration with respect to $r$ are from $r = 0$ to $r = 2\cos \theta$

Comment: NicetoseeyouonlineAmy:+)

Comment: $r=\pm\sqrt{2}\cos\theta$ is not the correct equation of the boundary circle in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ and $dx\, dy = r\, dr\,d\theta$ (same is true for $dy\,dx$)

For a boundary of $x^2+y^2=2x$, transforming this into polar yields the equation $r^2=2r\cos\theta$. Solving this for $r$ gives two answers $r=0$ and $r=2\cos\theta$ (since

$r^2=2r\cos\theta \Longleftrightarrow r^2-2r\cos\theta = 0 \Longleftrightarrow r(r-2\cos\theta)=0$.

These solutions provide your limits for $r$.

Comment: use translated polar coordinates given by x=rcos(theta) + 1 and y = rsin(theta) to evaluate the integral function f(x,y)= x^2+y^2 bounded by x^2+y^2 = 2x

Comment: and what i did was $r= sqrt(2rcos(theta) + 1)$ and r = 0 for my inner integral and the outer integral was from 0 to pi/2. But evaluating the inner integral I dont what to do with the r attached to the cos(theta)

Comment: Having the boundary in the original problem would have been more helpful than saying translated polar coordinates.

Comment: sorry that's my bad on my part

Comment: If you need more info on how to proceed, I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @John Habert, the Hint just clued in :D

Comment: No, you should take $r = 0$ to $r = 2\cos\theta$ as your inner bounds for $r$.

Comment: Which is what I said before I spelled out the solution method. I may need to organize my post a little better.